# Query equivalentes (com e sem alias) não funcionam igual

Tags: sql, alias

A query só funciona quando com alias no código. O código sem alias não funciona. pq? Não deveriam ambas funcionar iguais?

**1.** NÃO FUNCIONA - Retorna apenas coluna accounts.name

```
SELECT region.name, sales_reps.name, accounts.name
FROM sales_reps 
JOIN region 
ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
JOIN accounts 
ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
ORDER BY accounts.name;
```

**2**. FUNCIONA - Retorna as colunas explicitadas no SELECT

```
SELECT r.name region, s.name rep, a.name account
FROM sales_reps s
JOIN region r
ON s.region_id = r.id
JOIN accounts a
ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Schema:

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0lXP.png)
[Resultado query certa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4s9V.png)

Comment: No primeiro caso que não funciona, todas as 3 colunas possuem o mesmo nome, vai retornar somente o valor da última na aplicação que utilizar o índice 'name' no array retornado do banco, pode fazer como na segunda e fornecer aliases como: SELECT region.name as region, sales_reps.name as rep, accounts.name as account.

Comment: @Benilson isso não deveria ser a razão para isso, se bem referenciada uma query pode retornar mais de uma coluna com o mesmo nome. **JV** pode montar um exemplo mostrando o problema? Como está a query isso deveria resultar.. pode monstar aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ outra coisa **muito importante**, qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: Veja aqui um exemplo com as mesmas queries e funciona bem, logo se não montrar um exemplo que replique o problema não podemos ajudar mais: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sATAfxrRcE79MaRyL7pJTk/1

Comment: @RicardoPontual no programa do próprio banco de dados, ele exibe as 3 colunas, correto, mas na aplicação, por exemplo PHP, quando se tenta utilizar os dados retornados do banco, como por exemplo $row['name'], não vai dar certo.

Comment: @Benilson mas quem falou de programa? a pergunta se restringe a query :)  eu entendo o que você diz, mas a pergunta não tem nada de php/programa etc, a dúvida é em relação à query apenas, e como demonstrei no exemplo, não se replica esse problema

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloquei o schema e o resultado esperado da query

Comment: @JVNóbrega só tem uma imagem com os dados, era preciso replicar o problema, tente fazer igual eu fiz no site db-fiddle.com e tente criar a tabela, por os dados e ver se o erro se repete. Importante, ainda não informou qual é o banco de dados

Comment: @RicardoPontual é isso? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDh2nGidk2nnPJTjeniL2g/0#&togetherjs=Bd4wHS6fd2

Comment: é isso, mas veja que eu adicionei lá a sua query e o problema não se replica, ele retorna as 3 colunas "name": https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDh2nGidk2nnPJTjeniL2g/1

Comment: @RicardoPontual Tem razão! funcionam iguais. Deve ser algum erro na plataforma daqui. Obrigado pela ajuda!!